# Algorithm that gives you any number n in base 3 in R

Tags: r, algorithm

I need to write an algorithm that gives you any number `n` in base 3 in R.
So far I wrote that:

```
NameOfTheFunction <- function(n) { while (n != 0) {
{q<- n%/%3}
{r <- n%%3}
{return(r)}
q<- n  } }
```

My problem is that I now need to stock every `r` in a vector. I've never done that and don't quite know how to handle it. I tried to find some things on the internet but I did not find anything really relevant to this particular situation.

Comment: You should ask such question on Stackoverflow. Shouldn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your function, use:

```
sapply(vector, FUN=function(n) return(NameOfTheFunction(n)))
```

What `sapply` does is, for a given `vector` of your choice, it will repeat the function `NameOfTheFunction(n)` using every element in your vector in place of `n` in the function. The result, in this case, will be a vector of every output from your vector.

For example:

```
vector <- c(10, 100, 1000, 10000)
NameOfTheFunction <- function(n) { while (n != 0) {
  {q<- n%/%3}
  {r <- n%%3}
  {return(r)}
  q<- n  } }
sapply(vector, NameOfTheFunction)
[1] 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but when I tried to apply what you gave, it did not work. I do not know what is wrong with this :
ternary <- function(n) { while (n != 0) {
     {q<- n%/%3}
     {r <- n%%3}
     {return(r)}
     q<- n   
 sapply(vector, FUN=function(n) return(ternary(n))) }}
> ternary(10)
When I write this in R, it displays just the last r (1) not all the rs while I need a vector where I will have all the rs.

Comment: I've edited my post to show you the exact code I used, including its output of `1 1 1 1`. All I did was create a vector, copy your function, and used sapply. Can you reedit the code in your comment? It's hard to tell what you used when it's not formatted when included in a comment. I am noticing you are missing two braces e.g. after `q<- n`, which would prevent your function from working.

Comment: Why not `sapply(vector, NameOfTheFunction)`?

Comment: That works too. I'm used to using `sapply` in a fashion similar to above, which doesn't change the functionality in this case. I'll update it with your `sapply` version, simply because it's more concise